# Is there a way to avoid me repeating my code in MVC Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to do something like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A1)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A1)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A2)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A2)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A3)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A3)
</div>
```

I'm using MVC3 and the razor view engine which is new to me. What I would like to do is to avoid having to repeat the same block of four lines with A1,A2,A3,A4 ... A20. Is there some way I can use a helper, template or some other feature to make it so I don't have to repeat many lines of code.

Answer (score 12):

One option is to use a partial view like @Ufuk mentions.

A better way IMO is to use an editor template, making use of MVC's built in conventions.

Instead of having single properties for A1, A2, etc. Put them in a `IEnumerable<Something> Somethings`.

Then do this in your View:

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Somethings)`

Then create an editor template called `Something.cshtml` and place it in `Shared\EditorTemplates`, and MVC will do an "implicit" for each loop and render out whatever is in the editor template for the model:

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorForModel()
   @Html.ValidationMessageForModel()
</div>
```

**Do not** use a *foreach* loop - it's unnecessary and avoidable code soup.

Editor template HTML is identical to partial, strongly-typed and all. The difference is the convention to look for the file, whereas partial views need the explicit partial view name.

What this means is if you change the type of the model, it will look for that template based on the model type, allowing for a very powerful convention-based approach - which is what MVC is all about.

Comment: +1 Great answer that's actually helped me with something I was scoping out to do in the next week or so.

Comment: @Rory - glad i could help. I have been using editor/display templates extensively. Even for simple things such as how to render out an enum. By creating an editor template for that, i can ensure every View that uses `EditorFor` or `DisplayFor` bound to that enum type uses that template. Very powerful. I only use partials now for layout or when the template needs more than the model itself.

Answer (score 6):

Create a partial view that's strongly typed to that class.

A_Partial.ascx

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model)
</div>
```

Then render them for each object.

```
@Html.Partial("A_Partial", model.A1)
@Html.Partial("A_Partial", model.A2)
@Html.Partial("A_Partial", model.A3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in an array:

```
@foreach(var item in new object[] { Model.A1, Model.A2 /* ... */ }) {
    <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.EditorFor(item)
       @* ... *@
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If possible, try putting all of them in a single array/dictionary and then use foreach.